# Need an algorithm to find something like a Hitting Set

Tags: java, algorithm

i need some help to find an Algorithm in Java for this problem:
Having the Classes A and B with links between them.
Now i have the following table:
[Table with links between A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhQox.png)

X means there is a link between An and Bn

Now the problem is how do i find the smallest set of B's to "hit" all of the A's
For example, if i implement this for a Greedy Algorithm it would take B3 because it has the most links to A's and then searching for others to fill the rest. This would give me a Set of 3 B's. But i need an algorithm to take B4 and B5 because it is the smallest set.

The question i like to ask you is, what is a good algorithm for this problem? Are there any "popular" Algorithms for this kind of problem? I thought it is something like a Hitting-Set Problem but i cant get a graph-representation out of it. It is also kind of hard to search for this problem because i dont know the name or something like a technical term of it.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's an NP complete problem, so in some sense there's no good (known) algorithm. If your examples are small, you can simply enumerate all subsets of Bs and pick the smallest one that covers A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NP complete, so there's no known simple (exact) solution that's guaranteed to be fast.

If your examples are small, you can simply enumerate all subsets of `B`s, and pick the smallest one that covers the `A`s. Obviously that's exponential even in the best case.

A better approach is to express the problem in a different form for which there exists reasonable solvers. One such form is as an integer linear program.

Here's an integer linear program that represents your example.

```
Minimize
obj:b1+b2+b3+b4+b5

Subject To
b1+b2+b3+b4 >= 1
b2+b4 >= 1
b3+b5 >= 1
b1+b2+b3+b4 >= 1
b1+b2+b3+b4+b5 >= 1
b3+b4 >= 1
b5 >= 1

Bounds
0 <= b1 <= 1
0 <= b2 <= 1
0 <= b3 <= 1
0 <= b4 <= 1
0 <= b5 <= 1

End
```

The "minimize" clause captures the idea that you want as small a solution as possible. The `i`th "Subject To" clause constrains the solution so that `A[i]` is covered. (Note: some of the constraints are duplicated because in your example some of the `A`s are adjacent to exactly the same sets of `B`s).

GLPK (or many of the other integer linear program solvers) can solve this, and even much larger examples. There are also Java libraries that interface with solvers.

You can run this online here: http://hgourvest.github.io/glpk.js/

The output is:

```
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.49
7 rows, 5 columns, 20 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
4 rows, 4 columns, 12 non-zeros
Scaling...
 A: min|aij| = 1  max|aij| = 1  ratio = 1
Problem data seem to be well scaled
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part = 4
 0: obj = 1  infeas = 4 (0)
*1: obj = 2  infeas = 0 (0)
*2: obj = 2  infeas = 0 (0)
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
{"b1":0,"b2":0,"b3":0,"b4":1,"b5":1}
```

On the last line you can see the optimal solution is `b4=b5=1` corresponding to the smallest set being `{B4, B5}`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried all Greedy Algorithms ??  You need to understand how can map your hits to algorithms. I think this link will help you alot

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

Try to use **Adjacency List Representation**

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-7-dijkstras-algorithm-for-adjacency-list-representation/

Comment: This answer would be next to useless if the links provided became stale/broken.  Please add more information to your answer (if that is what it is)